# In vim how to map "save" to ctrl-s

Tags: vim

In vim, how can I map "save" (`:w`) to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>.

I am trying "map" the command, but xterm freezes when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>.

If I give <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> still I see only a `^`, not `^S`.

Comment: what's wrong with Vim's usual :w ?
I'm *guessing* ctrl-s freezes your xterm because it freezes all output in terminals. ('stty -ixon' might help)

Comment: Pressing (Escape shift colon w Enter) takes about 3 times longer than pressing Ctrl-s.  Although I have found pressing ctrl-s causes carpal tunnel more than Esc shift colon w enter, it spreads out the strain to have two options to save.

Comment: after years of what the hell did i do to freeze my vi session... ctrl-q

Answer (score 170, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is a common command to terminals to stop updating, it was a way to slow the output so you could read it on terminals that didn't have a scrollback buffer.  First find out if you can [configure your xterm](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files) to pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> through to the application.  Then these map commands will work:

```
noremap <silent> <C-S>          :update<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <C-S>         <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <silent> <C-S>         <C-O>:update<CR>
```

BTW: if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> freezes your terminal, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get it going again.

Comment: works with OSX, iTerm2, ZSH, oh-my-zsh when you include "stty -ixon" in the .zshrc file

Comment: "stty -ixon" in your .bashrc is also required for Terminal.app with bash.

Comment: @ned-batchelder Is it ok if you map to Ctrl-W, instead? Will there be a problem with vim or terminal default commands?

Comment: @ThiG. `<C-W>` is usually used for window splitting and window commands

Comment: the BTW is was the reason the search engines landed me here, thanks.

Answer (score 82):

In linux with VI, you want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and have it save your document.  This worked for me, **put the following three lines in your .vimrc file**.  This file should be located in your home directory: `~/.vimrc`. If this file doesn't exist you can create it.

```
:nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
:imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
```

The first line says: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> within a document will perform a `:w <enter>` keyboard combination.

The second line says: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> within a document while in 'insert' mode will escape to normal mode, perform a `:w <enter`, then press `a` to get back into insert mode.  Your cursor may move during this event.

You may notice that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> performs an 'XOFF' which stops commands from being received (If you are using ssh).

To fix that, place these two commands in your ~/.bash_profile

```
bind -r '\C-s'
stty -ixon
```

What that does is turn off the binding of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and gets rid of any XOFF onscreen messages when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.  Note, after you make changes to your .bash_profile you have to re-run it with the command 'source .bash_profile' or logout/login.

More Info: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files

Comment: For gnome terminal doing adding 'stty -ixon' to my .bashrc was enough.

Comment: :imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a  <----- This won't work as expected when at the beginning of the line ('a' will append instead of insert, which is what I'd expect). Is there are way to make it do 'a' or 'i' according to where the cursor is?

Comment: Could you please explain why you use 2 `imap` commands?  It seems like you only need `imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a`.  Thanks.

Comment: I thought the 2nd imap command line had significance, but on further inspection it does nothing.  Excellent catch, I removed the lame line.

Comment: I recommend the nonrecursive mappings (noremap vs nmap) to avoid unexpected pain down the road. See  http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a instead of i?

Answer (score 15):

vim

```
# ~/.vimrc
nnoremap <c-s> :w<CR> " normal mode: save
inoremap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>l " insert mode: escape to normal and save
vnoremap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR> " visual mode: escape to normal and save
```

zsh (if you use)

```
# ~/.zshrc
# enable control-s and control-q
stty start undef
stty stop undef
setopt noflowcontrol
```

bash (if you use)

```
# ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc
# enable control-s and control-q
stty -ixon
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `vnoremap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR> # visual mode: escape to normal and save` ?

Comment: BTW, looks like `#` doesn't work for comments in `.vimrc`. Use the double quote (`"`): `" <comment txt>`

Answer (score 12):

## Mac OSX Terminal + zsh?

### In your .zprofile

```
alias vim="stty stop '' -ixoff; vim"
```

**Why?, What's happening?** See [Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files), but basically for most terminals **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>** is already used for something, so this alias vim so that before we run vim we turn off that mapping.

### In your .vimrc

```
nmap <c-s> :w<cr>
imap <c-s> <esc>:w<cr>a
```

**Why? What's happening?** This one should be pretty obvious, we're just mapping **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>** to different keystrokes depending on if we are in normal mode or insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nvim & init.lua add the following lines

```
vim.keymap.set({'i'}, '<C-s>', '<C-o>:w<ENTER>')
vim.keymap.set({'n'}, '<C-s>', ':w<ENTER>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim ships with a file `mswin.vim` that maps the more popular shortcuts we all know and love from Windows applications. As documented in [`:help mswin.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/gui_w32.txt.html#mswin.vim), the line

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
```

will provide support for <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> etc. and - undocumented but true - <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> to save the buffer, even in *Insert mode*.
Instead of re-inventing the wheel, use this one-liner to get the most shortcuts with the least unwanted side effects.

Actually, `mswin.vim` provides the following mappings:

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode (<C-O> doesn't work well when
" using completions).
noremap <C-S>       :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S>      <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S>      <Esc>:update<CR>gi
```

And yes, it does work on Linux as well (as long as freezing terminals are not the problem as explained in the accepted answer).