# keyboard shortcuts creation ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to create a keyboard shortcut to save my file in vim, so I would like to map control alt S to ESC, :, w, ENTER, a. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this :

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files

Or this:

[In vim how to map "save" to ctrl-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446320/in-vim-how-to-map-save-to-ctrl-s)

Or this:

http://sigttou.com/vim-ctrl-s