# Looking for better way to map some F key in Vim

Tags: vim

I currently map my <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> as following:

```
map <F2> :tabn <CR>
map <F3> :tabp <CR>
imap <Esc> :tabn <CR>
imap <Esc> :tabp <CR>
```

I try to figure out how to map the normal/insert mode at the same time.
I spent some times on googling around without any luck.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a command in vim for all modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177411/create-a-command-in-vim-for-all-modes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've found so far is:

```
nnoremap <F2> :tabn<CR>
imap     <F2> <C-O><F2>
nnoremap <F3> :tabp<CR>
imap     <F3> <C-O><F3>
```

Still an extra line for each key, but at least the actual command (`:tabn`, `:tabp`) is only mentioned once (and only needs to be changed in one place if you want to change it).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly in my opinion, these mappings are probably not worth it.

- `gt`/`gT` already exist to move between tabs. See `:h gt`
- Normal mode is crucial to Vim and it makes sense to use this mode and not insert mode for movement between tabs. It is called normal mode for a reason as it is the mode you should normally be in.

#### Aside about tabs and buffers

Your mappings suggest a heavy tab centric workflow. I know it might sound weird but maybe try and use less tab panes together with a more buffers centric workflow. Here are some nice posts about it:

- [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329)
- [Use buffers effectively!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)